# How to connect data base using jndi datasource in weblogic

Tags: java, database, oracle10g, weblogic, jndi

How to connect data base using jndi datasource in weblogic. i am using following code but it is giving null value for connection

```
Context ctx = null;
    Hashtable evn = new Hashtable();
                evn.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    evn.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7001");    

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
     ctx = new InitialContext(evn);
     javax.sql.DataSource ds 
                      = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup ("mydatasource");
          conn = ds.getConnection();
                  }catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println();
                    // TODO: handle exception
                                }
```

Comment: When you get an objects (DataSource) from your lookup, then the lookup (JNDI) is working in general. So I guess it is an configuration problem of the connection itself.

Comment: have you configured mydatasource in the weblogic console?

Comment: Check in the jndi tree of the weblogic server via weblogic console if the datasource is bound to the jndi tree

Comment: yes i have configured mydatasource in weblogic console

Answer (score 0):

Append this to clarify more about exception reason

```java
catch(Exception sqlExp)
{        
   throw new SQLException("getConnection :: Exception"+sqlExp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. post the exception as suggested by Stano
2. on weblogic console test the connection 
   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13737/jdbc_datasources.htm#CHDIIFHH
3. did you target the datasource to weblogic server where the application works?

Answer (score 0):

```
     //try this code:

     Connection con = null;
     DataSource datasource = null;

     Context initialContext = new InitialContext();

     // "jdbc/MyDBname" >> is a JNDI Name of DataSource on weblogic

     datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/MyDBname");

     con = datasource.getConnection();
```